# Laravel 5 Cron Job On Godaddy Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task

Hello and thanks in advance,

I am using Laravel 5 hosted on Godaddy. I am trying to get a cron job to run but I keep getting this message:

**Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.11
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
No input file specified.**

I haven't done a cron myself in Laravel before and I decided to follow this tutorial https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel

Everything works fine when I run php artisan DeleteInActiveUsers:deleteusers but the Cron doesn't.

Below are the commands I have tried in the Cron, the file name I created based on the tut is called DumpZohoContacts.php.

**Note: I have added */usr/bin/php*    &    *-q* but it still doesn't work I also ran app_path(); to see my app path and check that. And the code is not the issue since it runs fine by itself**

Cron Commands:

> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/rms/artisan schedule:run
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/artisan schedule:run
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/rms/artisan zohoDumpToDb:dumpContacts
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/artisan zohoDumpToDb:dumpContacts
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/rms/app/Console/Commands/artisan schedule:run
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/rms/app/Console/Commands/artisan zohoDumpToDb:dumpContacts
>
> php /home/[hidden]/public_html/rms/app/Console/Commands/DumpZohoContacts.php

Comment: i see dozen of dupes, hope you tried them all

Comment: It should be something like `/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/artisan schedule:run /dev/null >> 2&1`

Comment: @rtfm > I have tried them all with different combinations.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks actually your syntax got me further but now I get /bin/bash: 1: command not found im gonna go into the actual commands path and try it out ill let you know

Comment: Didn't work not sure what im doing wrong if you guys need anything from me code etc let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my Email, I used to get this warning. Iff you have entered an incorrect command

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'magickwand' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.37
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

If you are about to schedule the command as once a day (i.e., 00:00) the same time should be reflected in a `$schedule->command();` object

In `Kernel.php` you should specify

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('SyncAPIOrders:orders')
               ->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
               ->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```

You should add the command from the cPanel server as

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xyz/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel 2>&1
```

This will keep all the logs in `/home/xyz/public_html/log_laravel`

```
Running scheduled command: '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' SyncAPIOrders:orders > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```